# Using $_GET funcion instead of using plain text

Tags: php, string, strlen

I have a file on my server called "form2.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<form action="strlen2.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="text13"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

I have it transfer to another file called "strlen2.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<?php

$text="$_GET["text13"]";
$more="Too much! Take away some text.";
$equal="Great! You entered the right amount.";
$less="Not enough! Enter some more text.";

if(strlen($text)>3)
{
echo $more;
}
elseif(strlen($text)==3)
{
echo $equal;
}
else
{
echo $less;
}
?>
```

What can I change on line 3 that makes it execute the `$_GET` function instead of looking at it as plain text?

Comment: Your code can not works. `$text="$_GET["text13"]";` is a **Parse error**. How can your page works fine ?

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I just stated learning PHP yesterday so I'm still new.

Answer (score 7):

`$_GET` is a variable. Remove the quotes around it.

```
$text = $_GET['text13'];
```

Comment: always so fast in answering :(

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, the predefined `$_GET` variable is used to collect values in a form with `method="get"`.

```
<form action="strlen2.php" method="get">
```

and if you do `print_r($_GET);` in your `strlen2.php`, you'll be able to see the result.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes. $_GET is not a function, but an array.

```
$text = $_GET["text13"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value of $_GET['text13'] DOES happen to contain a reference to a function, you would need to do something like this:

```
$text = $_GET['text13'];
$text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text= $_GET["text13"];
```

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is not a function ;) it's a variable. Remove the quotes and it should work like a charm :)

eg :

```
$text=$_GET["text13"];
$more="Too much! Take away some text.";
$equal="Great! You entered the right amount.";
$less="Not enough! Enter some more text.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$text = $_GET["text13"];
....
```

Don't put quotes around the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

This would never work:

```
$text="$_GET["text13"]";
```

Use this instead:

```
$text = $_GET['text13'];
```